# How to lower or change my TTY resolution?

Tags: console, display, resolution

### How to lower or change my TTY (1-6) resolution?

System: Linux Mint 20.1 64-bit, kernel 5.4.0-74-generic, Nvidia proprietary display driver.

Here is [`dmesg` log direct view link](https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/public/dmesg.txt) after boot with these changes done:

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
```

`/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
#if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=auto ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768 ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1024x768 ; fi
...
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}
```

On UEFI, calling `videoinfo` for the list of supported resolutions:

[image: GRUB videoinfo]

---

I feel desperate already as nothing I tried changes my laptop's native resolution of 3840x2160.

---

After changes, these were called:

```
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```